# При получении изображения с камеры возникает ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, cv2

Когда я получал изображение с камеры возникла такая ошибка

```
[ WARN:0@0.481] global cap_msmf.cpp:471 `anonymous- 
namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with 
error status: -2147024809
[ WARN:0@0.481] global cap_msmf.cpp:483 `anonymous- 
namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is 
failed with error status: -2147024809
[ WARN:1@0.481] global cap_msmf.cpp:1759 CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't 
grab frame. Error: -2147024809
```

Вот код:

```
import cv2
# получаем видео с камеры
video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# пока не нажата любая клавиша — выполняем цикл
while cv2.waitKey(1)<0:
    # получаем очередной кадр с камеры
    hasFrame,frame=video.read()
    # если кадра нет
    if not hasFrame:
        # останавливаемся и выходим из цикла
        cv2.waitKey()
        break
    # выводим картинку с камеры
    cv2.imshow("Face detection", frame)
```

Библиотека cv2 у меня установлена. Скажите пожалуйста как можно исправить эту ошибку?